# ASP.NET MVC map Model to BLL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I have a project for my MVC4 site, one for my BLL and one for my DLL.

In my MVC4 site, should I simply, inside my controllers, new up BLL objects and map them to Model objects?  I want the BLL classes and Model classes to remain separate, but I am not sure if I should just map them over or if there is another, better way.

I want whatever way I relate the Model classes to their BLL classes to be really simple, however.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the mapping by hand in your controller or helper methop, that is fine to MVC, but I would suggest doing the mapping using some component like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Again, the automapper is optional, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into AutoMapper